# Pandas not reading in file correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, fixed-width, import-from-csv

I have the data file given here:: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8lsvigjjpjhdlap/AAD3VpFdBifGMxrq5C-6yhpPa?dl=0

and the following code::

```
import pandas as pd       
df = pd.read_table('Best_2018_Table1.txt', sep=r"\s*")
```

but something is breaking and pandas doesn't read this admittedly badly formatted table::

```
df.columns
df['PS1gmag']
```

What's the best way to read in this spaces-for-columns type of file??

Comment: I wanted to suggest `sep=r"\s\s+", engine = "python"`, but this won't fix it. There is no easy way because you don't have a consistent use of delimiters in your file. Some columns are separated by one whitespace, some by more. Some entries contain also a whitespace, e.g., the header `AllWISE.1 photometry (1`. So how would a parser know, if a word is the next column or the same entry?

Comment: I have the file format (A27, A11, F4.1, A17, F4.1, A15, F4.1, A5, A6 etc.) for all 62 rows. But I have no idea if, or even how, I pass this to pandas.

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by A27 or F4.1. Is this some fixed width column file?

Comment: That looks like one of our or CDS's fixed width files but where did the header go? If it had the header, then I'd import vi astropy then use the built in to_pandas for astropy tables.

Comment: @npross yep, I created this file, which before had a header that defined the fixed width columns. All our tables can be read with astropy.table.Table using format="ascii.cds" -- do you need more help than that?

Comment: @Gus, excellent, thanks.                                                                                    
table = ascii.cds("Best_2018_Table1_full.txt") doesn't work, but                        table = ascii.read("Best_2018_Table1_full.txt") where this is the full file with the header, does. No one I have asked actually knew about this cds option.

Comment: @npross you'll want the original file (http://iopscience.iop.org/0067-0049/234/1/1/suppdata/apjsaa9982t7_mrt.txt) , and to use from astropy.table import Table ; data = Table("apjsaa9982t7_mrt.txt", format="ascii.cds") and it should just work.

Comment: fwiw, I'm not "answering" the panda's question so I don't think I'm answering the actual question via comments, rather clarifying what should be the higher level solution to the problem. I hope the SO rules aren't being broken here.

Comment: @gus. Got it. All good here. Mega thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is searching for 0 or more whitespace characters. Try \s+ so that you are ensured a minimum of 1 space.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has fixed width fields (except for the headers) and should be read as such.

Using whitespace as separator won't work because some fields are empty and will put the data in the wrong column, for example:

```
2MASS_J00492677-0635467     M8.5         8.5 null                   M8.5
WISEPC_J004928.48+044100.1  null             L9                19.  L9
WISE_J004945.61+215120.0    null             T8.5              28.5 T8.5
SIPS_J0050-1538             L1:         11.  L0.5              10.5 L1:
```

Would become:

```
2MASS_J00492677-0635467     M8.5        8.5   null  M8.5
WISEPC_J004928.48+044100.1  null        L9    19.   L9
WISE_J004945.61+215120.0    null        T8.5  28.5  T8.5
SIPS_J0050-1538             L1:         11.   L0.5  10.5  L1:
```